# Spot Light size in principled volume Bug in 4.0

Tags: lighting, volumetrics

I guess I find a bug, there is this strange thing when you combine principled volume with spotlight or point light. That you see a hard edge of the light.
Its gone when you make a higher radius but than its not that what I want.

Look my images, same settigs diffrent result.

[image]

Comment: Since this is either behavior intended by the developers or actually a bug, the question is off-topic on this site and should probably be reported as a bug via _Help_ > _Report a Bug_.

Comment: Hello. @GordonBrinkmann  agreed.. I can't be absolutely sure this is not a setting required in 4.0 that was not required before, though, so will leave up for a little while to see if anyone comes up with a by-the-book fix.

Comment: Hi, @3D bob.. this does look as if it's probably a bug, so Gordon's comment may stand, and this should be reported, rather than asked here. But, personally, holding off closure for a little while,for reasons given above. If other mods know better, they may fairly disagree.

Comment: @RobinBetts I found out this is supposed to be intended behavior, and as long as the developers do not change their mind or add options to switch the behavior, I gave a new way of doing this or workaround as answer here: [4.0 Spot Lights](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304998/4-0-spot-lights/305005#305005)

Comment: Hello, @GordonBrinkmann  Great.. Thanks for the research and answer! 3D bob.. if the linked answer above  is a fix for you, please report here, and we can close this post as a duplicate. If not, you can edit to point out the difference.

Comment: @RobinBetts As far as I understand the reasoning behind this it is supposed to be more physically accurate regarding energy conservation etc., however the problem is for all people working artistically and not completely realistic this is a step back.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thank you guys for the opinion. So I am now sure that this is a bug and I report it. Thank you all

Comment: @3Dbob No, it's not a bug... as I said earlier, it was done intentionally. Your bug report will be closed just as mine.