# New Spot Light behavior in 4.0 no longer renders in a volume

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I have a model of the Abyss Cab 3 Mini sub. The model has a number of spotlights that cast a beams in a volume. It all works in 3.6 but in 4.0 all my spotlights are broken and don't work like the old spots. How do I get the 4.0 spots cast a beam rather than a circular glow that encompasses the whole fixture. this is not the way spot lights work. They cast a beam in a single direction and virtually no light in the opposite direction. 4.0 breaks every undersea model I have because of this lighting change.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Well, they seem to have changed the spotlight in version 4.0 as this question came up here before recently > [Spot Light size in principled volume Bug in 4.0](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304906/) and this might be unfortunate but not an issue for this site, because if this is not supposed to be like that it's a bug which should be reported via _Help_ > _Report a Bug_ or - if this behavior is intended by the developers - then users should inform them that this is not desired. But since we are only Blender users ourselves and not developers, we cannot do anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

I originally voted to close this question as rather being a bug or even intended behavior which makes this question off-topic for this site.

In the meantime I found out the spotlight is actually intended to work like that now and at least in the 4.0 Blender versions there will be no change to it. The googd thing about the new spotlight is, it respects the given radius better than the old one.

However, for everyone who wants to replicate/substitute the previous spotlight behavior, here is a workaround:

Instead of using the *Spot*, change the light to *Area* instead. Change the *Shape* to *Disk* and the size (since this represents the diameter now, not the radius) to twice the size as it was before. Under *Beam Shape*, the previous angle for *Spot Size* now needs to be set as *Spread* for the area light (the default of the *Area* light is 180°).

Unfortunately the area light seems to be much much brighter than the spot light. In the volumetrics, a *Power* of 30 - 50 W seems to have a similar effect like a *Power* of 1000 W on the area light.

So this is not a perfect equivalent of the old spot light, but at least a usable workaround.

Here are some comparison images, first of all the previous spot light in older versions:

[image: spot light 3.6]

And this is what you are experiencing now in 4.0:

[image: spot light 4.0]

This is what you can get with an *Area* light, as you can see it is much brighter:

[image: area light 4.0]

This is the same with a reduced *Power* value of 40 W:

[image: reduced power]

Comment: There's also a YT video about lighting in 4.0 [here](https://youtu.be/92__vH2LWB0).

Comment: @JohnEason Yes, I know the video, but this just deals with how the new light linking works, it's not about how they changed the light objects themselves.