# Point light V3.6 vs V4.0 not same Radius effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I'm testing the unexpected V4 of Blender.
I'm looking a strange diférences:
For the Point light / Radius value = 0.25M it look diférent in Blender V4.0.1
[image]

The workaround shared in this post [New Spot Light behavior in 4.0 no longer renders in a volume](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304998/new-spot-light-behavior-in-4-0-no-longer-renders-in-a-volume/305005#305005)
not working in my case.
(I Can't change my light type Point to Area.)

I found another solution that provides an acceptable result for me.
I divided the Radius by 10.
0.25m set to 0.025 in B3D4. (It is possible to adjust the power value if needed)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the change made on point light behavior in 4.0.
See 'Lights' section of https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Shading
and the referenced issue here : https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/108505