why is my render result so dark?
I have already turned on all the light, but the render result is not same as the render view,it was so dark.
In blender 3.6 the render result was same as the render view, but in Blender 4.1 the render result was too dark
why?
here is my file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JYv5o_th-3ktUoNj27YwdpoulxivBGJ_/view?usp=sharing


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305709/point-light-v3-6-vs-v4-0-not-same-radius-effect

@Leander: there are no point lights in the scene....

it is only hdr in the scene....and i use aces color

and if i delet all the materials, it will be totoly dark

have no idea, tryed everything......

Your file is really big (500MB), but your scene is only an HDRI and has no point or area lights (or they are disabled in the render).
I'll try to fix the problem when I open it.

tbh i would open a bug report for that. The difference between the 2 Blender versions is immense.

@KISKAart: you are right, but in the old version that worked.

@Chris I found the problem, it was a hidden object not letting light through the window, I am writing an answer now.

@KISKAart: i still wonder why that worked in the old Blender version....!?

Interesting, but I don't know, I'm using Blender 4.1 at the moment.

Note:
My system is running out of memory, please optimise your files. it is 500 mb, you can use instancing on chairs and tables.
The problem is Box018, it's hidden in the viewport but visible in the render.
Remove it or hide it in the render, it should let light pass through the window.
Result:



hi, thanks!!!!! it was really nice of you!!

@MeiyingLu Instead of thanking in the comments, you can accept the answer. Comments are used to ask for clarification. What should I do when someone answers my question?
